# windows 8 find files modified in last hour

Tags: windows, windows-8, search, find, date-modified

In windows 8 I am trying to find files modified in the last hour. After reading these two links I thought I could do this.

```
System.DateModified:YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
```

So I tried

```
System.DateModified:>2016-01-04T05:00
```

and this since the first way didn't work.

```
System.DateModified:<2016-01-04T05:00
```

It is supposed to be:

```
January 4, 2016 at 5 AM
```

I added a `>` because I thought you need that for after the date and time listed.  Is there an easier way to do this?

http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266512%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As you stated in your post, you need to use the syntax

> System.DateModified:YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss

For some reason you didn't add the seconds:

`System.DateModified:>2016-01-04T05:00:00`

Should be what you require.

Comment: Thank you. The links I read made it seem like seconds was optional.